# WampServer icons doesn't work

Tags: apache, configuration, wampserver

I've just installed WampServer 2.5, and scripts runs well.
Only Wamp Icons doen't works.
For example if I browse a folder project's, when Wamp lists files doesn't appear the icon, as show below:

[image: esample]

Trying to right click on an icon, in new tab opened appears the message:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /icons/unknown.gif on this server.

So in httpd.conf i've changed permission in directory **/** and **c:/wamp/www/**, setting **Require all granted**.
After this, now I've this error:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /icons/unknown.gif was not found on this server.

How can I pass right icons path to wampserver?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Uncomment the line `Include conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf` in `httpd.conf` file
2. Make sure `httpd-autoindex.conf` file has this:

   ```
   Alias /icons/ "icons/"

   <Directory "icons">
       Options Indexes MultiViews
       AllowOverride None
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   </Directory>
   ```
3. Restart the server

Comment: It works, thank you so much! In my httpd-autoindex.conf there was "c:/Apache24/icons" instead "icons".

Comment: Edit: with this method, I've restored previously changed permission in directory / and c:/wamp/www/ inside httpd.conf, and all works fine. Great

Comment: Same problem, followed all the three staps and still getting `You don't have permission to access /icons/back.gif on this server`